# Dropdown menu is hiding behind div

Tags: html, css

I am new to css my dropdown menu is hiding behind the div please help me to find out the problem. my HTML and CSS code is:

```css
<style>
 *
 {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  
 }
 body
 {
  background-color:mintcream;
  
 }
  #header
  {
   
   height:260px;
   width:auto;
   margin:5px;
  }
  
  #headerimg
  {
   height: 260px;
   width:100%;
   
  }
  
    
 #wrap #menu
  {
   width:550px;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:10px;      
  }
  
  #wrap
  {
   height:50px;
   background-color:lightsalmon;
   border:1px solid white;
   border-radius:5px;
  }
  
  
 #wrap #menu ul li
  {
   background-color:black;
   border-radius:5px;
   width: 120px;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   list-style-type:none;
   margin-left: 3px;
   
  }
  
 #wrap #menu ul li a{
   color:white;
   text-decoration:none;
   display:block;
  }
  
  #wrap #menu ul li a:hover
  {
   background-color:mistyrose;
   color:orangered;
   border-radius:5px;
   
  }
  
 #wrap #menu ul li ul li
  {
   
   display:none;
  }
  
 #wrap #menu ul li:hover ul li
  {
   
   display:block;
   
  }
  
  #content
  {
   
   width:100%;
   height:500px;
   background-color: teal;
   margin:5px;
  }
  #content1
  {
   width:50%;
   height:500px;
   background-color: yellow;
   float:left;
  }
  #content2
  {
   width:50%;
   height:500px;
   background-color:red;
  float:left;
  }
 </style>
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <img  id="headerimg" src="doc.jpg" />
    
 </div>

 <div id="wrap">
<div id="menu">
 
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hospital</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
   </ul>
   
   
  </li>
 </ul>
 
</div>


</div>

<div id="content">
 <div id="content1"> </div>
 <div id="content2"> </div>

</div>
</body>
```

I am new to css. My dropdown menu is hiding behind the div. Please help me to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below css

```
 ul {position: relative; z-index: 99999; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add position:relative in "`#wrap #menu ul li`" . I think your problem was solved. If you have any other problem then put it here.

Thanks for asking.